# How do I allow others to embed my custom Google Map?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've made a custom Google Map with custom tiles and markers for a fictitious world. It's not public yet but the most obvious correlation is mapwow.com. Is it possible to allow others to now embed MY custom map into their sites or applications? Most of the search results are second-level only (Google > My Site) and I'm ideally looking for third level (Google > My Site > Their Site). My guess is that this would be possible using a) custom URL parameters to center the viewport on a specified lon/lat and b) an IFRAME that points to that URL on my site, but I'm wondering if there is a better or "official" way to do such a thing. An IFRAME isn't really a commonly supported tag in forum or wiki software.